# Is the zero sequence component considered balanced?

Tags: electric-machine

how is the zero sequence component is balanced while the three vectors are inphase and not displaced from each other by 120°?

Isn't the definition of a balanced system is one in which the magnitudes of all phases are equal and are spaced out by 120°?

The confusion came from the book below:
[image]

The source:
Electrical Power Systems
By
C L WADHWA
2012 by New Academic Science Limited
ISBN : 978 1 906574 39 0

Comment: It's using a different meaning of "balanced", I suppose

Comment: "Equi-spaced" does not necessarily mean that the angle is *strictly* greater than zero, it can be zero. It means that the differences between them are equal. So the assertion is true: they are the same magnitude, and same angle, which means they are equi-spaced at zero degrees difference between them.

Comment: @a concerned citizen please make a formal answer.

Comment: @OMAR When using the ping operator, `@`, use `TAB` to cycle between the names and make sure that there are no spaces. "a concerned citizen" should appear "aconcernedcitizen". Otherwise there are no notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Equi-spaced" does not necessarily mean that the angle is strictly greater than zero, it can be zero. It means that the differences between them are equal. So the assertion is true: they are the same magnitude and the same angle, which means they are equi-spaced at zero degrees difference between them.